# jodatime days period type problem/error

Tags: java, time, jodatime

I have a problem with jodatime api.  I can't understand why this test doesn't works. I need resolve how many days, hours, mins and seconds I have in X milliseconds. But the days value aren't resolved.... any idea?

```
@Test
public void testTime() {
    long secs = 3866 * 24 * 35;
    long msecs = secs * 1000;
    //Period period = duration.toPeriod();


    PeriodType periodType = PeriodType.forFields(
            new DurationFieldType[]{
                    DurationFieldType.days(),
                    DurationFieldType.hours(),
                    DurationFieldType.minutes(),
                    DurationFieldType.seconds(),
            });
    Duration duration = Duration.standardSeconds(secs);
    Period period = duration.toPeriod(periodType, GregorianChronology.getInstance());

    System.out.println("days:" + period.getDays());
    System.out.println("hours:" + period.getHours());
    System.out.println("mins:" + period.getMinutes());
    System.out.println("seconds:" + period.getSeconds());
    PeriodFormatter periodFormatter = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
            .printZeroAlways()
            .minimumPrintedDigits(2)
            .appendDays()
            .appendSeparator(":")
            .appendHours()
            .appendSeparator(":")
            .appendMinutes()
            .appendSeparator(":")
            .appendSecondsWithOptionalMillis()
            .toFormatter();
    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    periodFormatter.printTo(stringBuffer, period);
    System.out.println(">>>" + stringBuffer);
}
```

the output is
days:0
hours:902
mins:4
seconds:0
00:902:04:00

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440557/joda-time-period-to-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to normalize the period using:

```
Period normalizedPeriod = period.normalizeStandard();
```

or

```
Period normalizedPeriod = period.normalizeStandardPeriodType();
```

Then you can use the normalizedPeriod and see the results you are looking for.
As a quick test I modified your junit test case and added the line:

```
period = period.normalizedStandard();
```

right after your create the period from the duration.

Answer (score 1):

The chronology that you are using may not consider days to be precise. Instead of GregorianChronology, try using `IOSChronology.getInstanceUTC()`.