# Correct Hibernate type for TimeDuration in grails/groovy domain class?

Tags: hibernate, grails, groovy, mapping

using TimeDuration in one of my Grails/Groovy classes I get an exception when starting the grails app.

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: groovy.time.TimeDuration
```

usage in domain class

```
import groovy.time.TimeDuration
class Result {
    TimeDuration overall
}
```

which type should I define?

Comment: Indirect answer: install the [joda plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/joda-time) and use Joda [Durations](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Duration.html). The plugin maps the user types automatically for you.

Comment: I thought about this before, but wanted to try without it at first. thanks for remarking again!

Comment: No problem. From what I've seen, it looks like you'd probably have to write your own UserType to correctly persist the field.

Comment: persisting is done by the plugin, that works fine. But what I did not found yet is how to handle joda-time to and from string!?

Comment: If you add your comment as an answer, I would mark this as the solution.

Comment: I added an answer. I'm not sure I follow your last comment, though, about "joda-time to and from string". Can you elaborate?

Comment: if you have `Duration overallTime = new Duration(42000)` and you want to print this in a GSP-File it looks something like `PT42S`. I am looking for some kind of formating (e.g. showing only hours or days) this joda time.

Comment: You can turn the `Duration` into a [`Period`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html) and use a [`PeriodFormatterBuilder`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/PeriodFormatterBuilder.html) ([example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440557/joda-time-period-to-string)). You might try [creating a TagLib](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/guide/6.%20The%20Web%20Layer.html#6.3%20Tag%20Libraries) for that, which you'd call using e.g. `<my:formatDuration duration="${myDurationValue}"/>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using Grails it would probably be more convenient to use the [Joda Time plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/joda-time) and its [`Duration`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Duration.html) type to store your values.

The plugin, when installed, provides Hibernate mappings for many of the library's types (including `Duration`).

It's likely that if you continue along with Groovy's `TimeDuration` that you'll have to write your own `UserType`; I didn't find one after a few searches.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Date`. This will use the default "timestamp" for the date type in the db. Optionally you can configure hibernate specifically with other formats for your Date field via  hbm files/annotations.

Comment: using
`static mapping = {
  overall type:'date'
}`
results in DB using Type date and this brings up the error
`groovy.time.TimeDuration cannot be cast to java.util.Date`
using `timestamp` results in a similar error.

Answer (score 0):

```
import groovy.time.TimeDuration

class Result {
    Date overall
}
```

You can use this Date type for storing date and time, and this date and time will be mapped to timestamp by hibernate..

Comment: I do not see how Date/Time will store an ammount of time like 30mins ?!