# Convert JodaTime duration to string

Tags: java, jodatime, duration

I have movie with duration 127 seconds. I wanna display it as `02:07`. What is the best way to implement this?

Comment: I have temporary implemented this with `org.apache.commons.lang.time.DurationFormatUtils`

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440557/joda-time-period-to-string

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```java
Duration yourDuration = //...
Period period = yourDuration.toPeriod();
PeriodFormatter minutesAndSeconds = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
     .printZeroAlways()
     .appendMinutes()
     .appendSeparator(":")
     .appendSeconds()
     .toFormatter();
String result = minutesAndSeconds.print(period);
```

Answer (score 27):

I wanted this for myself and I did not find llyas answer to be accurate.
I want to have a counter and when I had 0 hours and 1 minute I got `0:1` with his answer- but this is fixed easily with one line of code!

```java
Period p = time.toPeriod();
PeriodFormatter hm = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
    .printZeroAlways()
    .minimumPrintedDigits(2) // gives the '01'
    .appendHours()
    .appendSeparator(":")
    .appendMinutes()
    .toFormatter();
String result = hm.print(p);
```

This will give you `02:07`!

Comment: This does seem to work better and I would upvote in preference to the accepted answer

Comment: I agree with Brian, the `minimumPrintedDigits(2)` was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

### java.time

Quoted below is a notice from the [home page of **Joda-Time**](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/):

> **Note that from Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to `java.time` (JSR-310) - a core part of the JDK which replaces this project**.

### Solution using `java.time`, the modern date-time API

You can use [`java.time.Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) which is modelled on [ISO-8601 standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and was introduced with *Java-8* as part of [JSR-310 implementation](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/pfd/jsr310/JSR-310-guide.html). With *Java-9* some more convenience methods were introduced.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.Duration;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Duration duration = Duration.ofSeconds(127);
        // Default format
        System.out.println(duration);

        // Custom format
        // ####################################Java-8####################################
        String formattedElapsedTime = String.format("%02d:%02d", duration.toMinutes(), duration.toSeconds() % 60);
        System.out.println(formattedElapsedTime);
        // ##############################################################################

        // ####################################Java-9####################################
        formattedElapsedTime = String.format("%02d:%02d", duration.toMinutesPart(),
                duration.toSecondsPart());
        System.out.println(formattedElapsedTime);
        // ##############################################################################
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
PT2M7S
02:07
02:07
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/MBOyPQ)

Learn about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.