# jodaTime PeriodFormatter not formatting correctly

Tags: java, android, kotlin, jodatime, periodformatter

I have this PeriodFormatter:

```
PeriodFormatterBuilder()
            .appendDays()
            .appendSuffix(
                " day",
                " days")
            )
            .appendSeparator(", ")
            .printZeroRarelyLast()
            .appendHours()
            .appendSuffix(
                " hours",
                " hours"
            )
            .appendSeparator(" ")
            .appendMinutes()
            .appendSuffix(" minute")
            .toFormatter()
            .let {
                Period(Seconds.seconds(seconds.toInt())).toString(it)
            }
```

I want to give seconds as input and get  x DAYS, x HOURS, x MINUTES back....
I get an empty String back when doing this. If i add "appendSeconds()" to the formatter creation I get the same amount of seconds back as a return value as I sent in..

I need the conversion, not just the amount, and I'm not interested in number of seconds, but how many minutes, hours and days it accounts to.. Anyone who can help?

Comment: Similar: [Convert seconds to years/days/hours/minutes automatically, using JodaTime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10891762/convert-seconds-to-years-days-hours-minutes-automatically-using-jodatime)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [Period.normalizedStandard()](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html#normalizedStandard--) to persuade your period to convert your seconds into minutes, hours and days.

```
            Period(Seconds.seconds(seconds.toInt())).normalizedStandard().toString(it)
```

(Not sure whether the empty round brackets `()` are needed in Kotlin. They are in Java, where I tested.)

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you very much.