# Time in milliseconds calculation

Tags: java, time, milliseconds, seconds

I have two string variables for timer i.e.

```
String StartTimer1 = "00:00:00";
String EndTimer2 = "23:59:59";
```

Now , I need to calculate the time left from the present time (lets say if it is 05: 30:00) once the timer has started and time left has to be in milliseconds.

Comment: have you tried something ?

Comment: Have you heard about Date and SimpleDateFormat Classes? or worst but functional have heard about String Parse?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: This is my homework. I am learning Java.  I found this link and I tried it. It works, but I want simplify it more. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11021838/parsing-duration-string-into-milliseconds

Comment: @ashlesha: if you delete this question, it will get you all lost reputation back.

Comment: You need to understand what is the point of your homework question. I can tell you how to do this easily in 2 ways using SimpleDateFormat or with String parse to int, but it could not be what your teacher want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here some tipps to get started:

You can parse the String to a Java Date like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
Date startTimer1Date = format.parse(StartTimer1);
```

You can get the current Date and Time like this:

```
Date dateNow = new Date();
```

And since you are working with time only (and not with date and time), you will need to manipulate the Date, Month and Year of all values to a common base, e.g. :

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(dateNow);
c.set(Calendar.YEAR, 1970);
c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
dateNow = c.getTime();
```

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. I really appreciate it. Everyone who visited this page , rated -ve to the question instead of atleast giving minimum guidance. I posted this question from my mom's account instead of asking the same question to her, which i am sure will be more better than posting here. THanks a lot.

Comment: With a question like that, it's not what you teacher want. But yeah it's an answer for your Question.