# How to parse dHHmm to Duration?

Tags: java, jodatime

I have a string in format `dHHmm` that stands for a duration of time, and want to get the equivalent `minutes`.

Therefore I'm trying to convert it into a `org.joda.time.Duration.getMinutes()` object. But there seems to be no kind of DurationParser that could be used for this.

How could I best convert this string?

This is what I tried, but did not work:

```
PeriodFormatter formatter = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
    .appendDays()
    .appendHours()
    .appendMinutes()
    .toFormatter();

assertTrue(formatter.parsePeriod("00310").getMinutes == 190); //failed with =0
```

Comment: have you tried `SimpleDateFormat`?

Comment: A Duration or Period is not a Date! Neither do I want to parse the string into a date, as it makes no sense

Comment: but you have no duration, but a simple `String` without any explanation of the format....

Comment: try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6403851/parsing-time-strings-like-1h-30min

Comment: or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11021838/parsing-duration-string-into-milliseconds

Comment: @Steffen thanks for the link, I was probably missing the right keyword. Anyway, I tried as suggested there, but it does not work (period is always = 0). Please see my update above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, first you want to get `org.joda.time.Duration` from `dHHmm`...

```
import org.joda.time.Duration;

public Duration fromTheFormat( String str ) {
    Duration dayDuration = Duration.standardDays( parseInt( str.substring( 0, 1 ) ) );
    Duration hourDuration = Duration.standardHours( parseInt( str.substring( 1, 3 ) ) );
    Duration minuteDuration = Duration.standardMinutes( parseInt( str.substring( 3, 5 ) ) );

    return dayDuration.plus( hourDuration.getMillis() ).plus( minuteDuration.millis() );
}
```

or

```
import org.joda.time.Duration;
import org.joda.time.Period;
import org.joda.time.format.PeriodFormatter;

public Duration fromTheFormat( String str ) {
    Period period = new Period( /* years = */ 0,
                                /* months = */ 0,
                                /* weeks = */ 0,
                                /* days = */ parseInt( str.substring( 0, 1 ) ),
                                /* hours = */ parseInt( str.substring( 1, 3 ) ),
                                /* minutes = */ parseInt( str.substring( 3, 5 ),
                                /* seconds = */ 0,
                                /* millis = */ 0
    );

    // or best one is
    PeriodFormatter pf = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
                           .minimumPrintedDigits( 1 )
                           .maximumParsedDigits( 1 )
                           .appendDays()
                           .minimumPrintedDigits( 2 )
                           .maximumParsedDigits( 2 )
                           .appendHours()
                           .appendMinutes()
                           .toFormatter();

    period = pf.parsePeriod( str );

    return period.toStandardDuration();
}
```

Comment: The second example is not valid Java. Java does not have named parameters, something like `years = 0` as an argument is a syntax error.

Comment: There is no `.minimumParsedDigits()` in `PeriodFormatterBuilder`!?

Comment: @membersound... yes... true.

Comment: Sorry, but: why do you post invalid code if you know it is invalid?

Comment: @membersound Was going to correct it... but forgot and posted.

Comment: OK but did you try it? For me it gives a result of: 10 minutes, which is obviously wrong.

Comment: So... I gave 3 options... I think first 2 work fine... if I did not make more typying mistakes...  I am still trying to correctly type the third one .

Comment: I tried your 1st soluation and indeed: `duration.getStandardMinutes() == 190` OK. But: `duration.getPeriod().getMinutes()==10`. Why? Note that it gives the same result as with your 3rd solution, which is strange. Would be nice if we could figure this out, as from the syntax point of view I'd like the 3rd solution most.

Comment: Actually I tried it in Scala console. That's why I had to rewrite here for Java, which led to typing mistakes.

Comment: @membersound that is fine... You are mis-understanding this... Period.getMinutes() returns minutes in this Period.. It does not return the total minutes. So...In current case this period has `0 days`, `3 hours` and `10 minutes`. Can we do anything about downvotes.. ?

Comment: @Jasper fixed... forgot to comment them out.