# How can I convert time from PT-4M-28.965S to 00:04:28.965

Tags: java, time, jodatime

I am calculating time difference in `hh:mm:ss.SSS` format

```
DateTime dt1;
DateTime dt2;
Period period;
final DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HH:mm:ss.SSS");

String endTime = "20:03:56.287";
String startTime = "19:59:27.322";
dt1 = format.parseDateTime(endTime);
dt2 = format.parseDateTime(startTime);
period = new Period(dt1,dt2);
System.out.println(period);
```

I get `PT-4M-28.965S`

How can I convert this to `00:04:28.965`

Comment: try `new Period(dt2,dt1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Period` formatting is performed by the `PeriodFormatter` class:

```
PeriodFormatter formatter = new PeriodFormatterBuilder().printZeroAlways()
                .appendHours().appendSeparator(":").appendMinutes()
                .appendSeparator(":").appendSeconds().appendSeparator(".")
                .appendMillis3Digit().toFormatter();
String dateString = formatter.print(period.normalizedStandard());
```

But this `dateString` will have a value as `0:-4:-28.-965`, because you have defined your `period` as this:

```
String endTime = "20:03:56.287";
String startTime = "19:59:27.322";
dt1 = format.parseDateTime(endTime);
dt2 = format.parseDateTime(startTime);
period = new Period(dt1, dt2);
```

where the value of `dt1` is greater than `dt2`, and so the `-` before `mm:ss:SSS`. To get the desired result, you need to change the order of parameters to `period`:

```
period = new Period(dt2, dt1);
```

and with this the above `PeriodFormatter` will return you `0:4:28.965`.

Comment: +1 for nice explanation. But I wanted the time in `hh:mm:ss.SSS` format. So, adding this `.minimumPrintedDigits(2)` method to the `formatter` object does the job.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to define a `PeriodFormatterBuilder` like so:

```
DateTime dt1;
DateTime dt2;
Period period;
final DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HH:mm:ss.SSS");

String endTime = "20:03:56.287";
String startTime = "19:59:27.322";
dt1 = format.parseDateTime(endTime);
dt2 = format.parseDateTime(startTime);
period = new Period(dt1,dt2);

PeriodFormatter fmt = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
  .appendHours()
  .appendSeparator(":")
  .appendMinutes()
  .appendSeparator(":")
  .appendSeconds()
  .appendSeparator(".")
  .appendMillis3Digit()
  .toFormatter();

System.out.println(fmt.print(period.normalizedStandard()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's a value of `Period.toString()`
Try using e.g. [getHours()](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html#getHours%28%29) and other `getXXX()` methods to extract values.

Here is a better answer: [Period to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440557/joda-time-period-to-string)