# Computing the difference of two dates

Tags: java, date, timezone

I have written a small program that shall print the difference between two `Date` objects:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
    final DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS");
    final Date start = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();

    Thread.sleep(1000);

    final Date end = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    final long startMilliseconds = start.getTime();
    final long endMilliseconds = end.getTime();
    final long runtimeMilliseconds = endMilliseconds - startMilliseconds;
    final Date runtime = new Date(runtimeMilliseconds);

    System.out.print("Start  : " + df.format(start));
    System.out.println("\t Milliseconds: " + startMilliseconds);
    System.out.print("End    : " + df.format(end));
    System.out.println("\t Milliseconds: " + endMilliseconds);
    System.out.print("Runtime: " + df.format(runtime));
    System.out.println("\t Milliseconds: " + runtimeMilliseconds);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Milliseconds from new Date object: " + runtime.getTime());
}
```

It gives the following output:

```
Start  : 13:24:54.000871     Milliseconds: 1408015494871
End    : 13:24:55.000871     Milliseconds: 1408015495871
Runtime: 01:00:01.000000     Milliseconds: 1000

Milliseconds from new Date object: 1000
```

The difference between the milliseconds is correct, but the newly created `Date` object has an extra hour added. The expected output for the `runtime` object would be: `00:00:01.000000`. I think this is because of my timezone (GMT+1). How can I compute the difference between two `Date` objects and get a new `Date` object, that does not include the extra hour, back? I **do not** want to use Joda-Time or another library.

Comment: Why `Calendar.getInstance().getTime()` but not just `System.currentTimeMillis()`?

Comment: And actually it is unclear what you are asking: you have already wrote  the code which do what you desire.

Comment: It is just a test program. In my real program I need the Date objects, too. Expected output is `00:00:01.000000`, but actual output is `01:00:01.000000`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/230126/how-to-handle-calendar-timezones-using-java

Comment: You are trying to store an amount of time (for example, 1000 milliseconds) in a `Date` object. But a `Date` object is unsuitable for storing *amounts* of time. A `Date` object is a timestamp, which always has a date and time. If you store "1000" in a `Date` object, then what you get is a timestamp set to 01-01-1970 00:00:01 GMT.

Comment: Okay, but for me the timestamp is set to `01-01-1970 01:00:01 GMT`.

Comment: For all you timezone sayers, what is the time delta is more than 24 hours? Then this solution would produce a completely wrong result. Time Zone is not the answer here. Date is not being used correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To reach your desired behavior you need to set the right time zone, i.e. `GMT-00`, because a `Date` object created with the constructor you use, will be the *milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT*.

To do that simply set the `DateFormat df`:

```
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-00"));
```

immediately after its instantiation (then also `Start` and `End` dates will be displayed with the new time zone) or before the printing of the new `Date runtime` (then `Start` and `End` dates will be displayed in your local time zone); after that you can reset your original local timezone, if you want to keep it for future use.

The output will be of this kind as you desire:

```
Start  : 11:51:37.000287     Milliseconds: 1408017097287
End    : 11:51:38.000287     Milliseconds: 1408017098287
Runtime: 00:00:01.000000     Milliseconds: 1000

Milliseconds from new Date object: 1000
```

Comment: This ignores the underlying issue, why store a time delta in a `Date` object?

Comment: you're right, but I followed what he described as desired behavior of his code.

Comment: Although it gives the correct output, if a peer or instructor were to review the code they might have to wonder, "is this really a Date?".

Comment: The other point is, what if the time delta is more than 24 hours? This would then be completely wrong.

Comment: I'm not an instructor nor a reviewer ;) And I don't think his code is for school-assignment nor a large business project, since he said that is just a test program :) But anyway, for sure from a theoretic point of view, you're right.

Answer (score 2):

You issue is that you are treating a time duration as a `Date`. 1000 ms does not make any sense as a `Date` since `Date` is MS since the epoch. Don't try to convert it to a `Date`, just use it as a `long`.

If you are using Java 8, consider [Duration](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html). Or you could use JodaTime. Seems like these might be overkill if you just need the `long`.

Per your question, to format it, it depends on if you are using Java 8. If so, use its `Duration`. Otherwise, use JodaTime & Duration, Period and PeriodFormatter. This is described in the post:

[joda-time-period-to-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440557/joda-time-period-to-string)

I will admit this is a more complicated solution than setting the time-zone as others have suggested. However, I suggest it is a more correct solution. This is especially true if the time delta exceeds a day. In that case this solution would be completely wrong.

If the time delta is 24h 1sec, your format of `HH:mm:ss.SSSSS` would show `00:00:01.00000` instead of '24:00:01.0000`

Comment: How can I print the time delta in the format `HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS`?

Comment: I understand what you are saying. Thanks for clarification. For now I will stick with the timezone solution since the differences wont exceed more than some minutes. But I will definitively take a look at Joda-Time, because I am still on java 7.

Comment: Definitely check it out. It is a much better Date library than the built-in one for Java. That is why they added the update in Java 8. Since you know you are less than 24h you should be good. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are using `Date` class, and more specifically, `SimpleDateFormat` class in wrong way.

You wrote in your question everything right: additional hour in `runtime` object is due to your time zone (GMT+1).

The internal representation of your `runtime` object is `time = 1000`, i.e. it is `00:00:01 of January 1, 1970 GMT`.

If you want to see exactly this date, you should modify your formatter in proper way:

```
    final DateFormat dfGmt0 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS");
    dfGmt0.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+0"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this Runtime: 01:00:01.000000     Milliseconds: 1000 beacuse your current time zone is UTC+01:00 . set time zone GMT-00 for the Dateformatter .