# Joda time calculating the days, hours, minutes, and seconds between two datetime objects

Tags: java, jodatime

I am trying to find the days, hours, minutes and seconds between two date/times. I thought I could use period and I tried the code below but I get a non nonsensical answer.

```
    DateTime dt1 = new DateTime("2004-12-13T21:39:45.618-06:00");
    DateTime dt2 = new DateTime("2004-12-13T21:39:45.618-08:00");
    Period p = new Period(dt1, dt2);

    System.out.println("Test: " + p);
```

From this I get output:

```
I/System.out: Test: PT2H
```

Not sure what this is meant to mean.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you explain why it's nonsensical and what output would make sense to you?

Comment: Because to me it makes no sense. I thought that made sense haha

Comment: Please specify what _does_ make sense to you. `PT2H` perfectly describes the period of 2 hours.

Comment: There you go  you explained it thanks

Comment: Whether I did or didn't explain it was entirely non-obvious to me because you didn't specify what exactly didn't make sense. But I'm glad if I managed to accidentally help you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`toString()`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/base/AbstractPeriod.html#toString(org.joda.time.format.PeriodFormatter)) method in [`Period`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html) gives you the value as [*ISO8601*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) duration format.

From the API:

> Gets the value as a String in the style of the ISO8601 duration
>   format. Technically, the output can breach the ISO specification as
>   weeks may be included. For example, "PT6H3M5S" represents 6 hours, 3
>   minutes, 5 seconds.

As you ask to get separately the *days*,*hours*,*minutes* and *seconds* you can use the convenient `get` methods from the API:

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.Period;

...
DateTime dt1 = new DateTime("2004-12-13T21:39:45.618-06:00");
DateTime dt2 = new DateTime("2004-12-13T21:39:45.618-08:00");
Period p = new Period(dt1, dt2);

System.out.println("DAYS: " + p.getDays())
System.out.println("HOURS: " + p.getHours());
System.out.println("MINUTES: " + p.getMinutes());
System.out.println("SECONDS: " + p.getSeconds());
```

Or alternatively as other answers suggests use [`PeriodFormatter`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/PeriodFormatter.html).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation it is really appreciated.  The to string method just gave the same answer. But it gives me a clear explanation of the output I was giving. Thanks again.

Comment: @NicholasMuir because `System.out.println` implicit invoke the `toString()` method on your object. Nice to help you.

Answer (score 2):

Period is printed in ISO format

> The standard ISO format - **P**yYmMwWd**D**T**hH**mMsS.

If you need to find days, hours, minutes and seconds between two days, you should convert period to specific type. E.g.:

```
  Period p = new Period(dt1, dt2);
  System.out.println("Days: " + p.toStandardDays().getDays());
  System.out.println("Hours: " + p.toStandardHours().getHours());
  System.out.println("Minutes: " + p.toStandardMinutes().getMinutes());
  System.out.println("Seconds: " + p.toStandardSeconds().getSeconds());
```

or use special static methods in classes `Days`, `Hours`, `Minutes` and `Seconds`

```
  System.out.println("Days: " + Days.daysBetween(dt1, dt2));
  System.out.println("Hours: " + Hours.hoursBetween(dt1, dt2));
  System.out.println("Minutes: " + Minutes.minutesBetween(dt1, dt2));
  System.out.println("Seconds: " + Seconds.secondsBetween(dt1, dt2));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll have to format the object of period. Refer this link
[Period to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440557/joda-time-period-to-string)

Answer (score 1):

You need to format your `Period`. A simple way is to use the default one like this:

```
PeriodFormat.getDefault().print(period)
```

You can also create your own format with `PeriodFormatter`.