# Joda time PeriodFormatterBuilder, can I omit weeks and use only days?

Tags: java, formatting, jodatime

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1440795/455796), but is it possible to use only month and days, not weeks?

For example, instead of "1 month 2 weeks 2 days", I want "1 month 16 days".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a solution similar to the [answer you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440557/period-to-string/1440795#1440795), but you'll also need to use a `org.joda.time.PeriodType` to normalized the period:

```java
// 1 month, 2 weeks and 2 days
Period p = new Period(0, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0);

PeriodFormatter fmt = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
    // months
    .appendMonths().appendSuffix(" month", " months").appendSeparator(" and ")
    // days
    .appendDays().appendSuffix(" day", " days")
    .toFormatter();
System.out.println(fmt.print(p.normalizedStandard(PeriodType.yearMonthDayTime())));
```

This will print:

> 1 month and 16 days